# EWS API trying get appointment starting from a modified date

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am currently working on an app that checks all appointments on an individual email, it can update appointments, delete them, create new etc. This part is working already.

I am now trying to put all appointment starting from a specified last modified time into a list, and here is my issue. Code:

```
public void getByModifiedDate(CalendarFolder calendar)
{
bool found = false;

string date;
Console.WriteLine("Modified date: ");
date = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

List<TAppointments> tempList = new List<TAppointments>();
var appointments = getAppointments(calendar);
//loop through every appts on calendar
foreach (Appointment a in appointments)
{

    if (a.LastModifiedTime.ToString() == date)
    {

        TAppointments app = new TAppointments(a.ICalUid.ToString(), a.Subject.ToString(), a.Start.ToString(), a.End.ToString(), a.LastModifiedTime.ToString());
        currentApp = app;
        tempList.Add(app);
        found = true;
    }

}
  if (!found)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("No appointment found.");
   }
    printAppointments(tempList); 
 }
```

Here I can only find a single item, because well that's what I coded. Is there a way to specified a starting date? Something like lastmodifiedtime >= date? I've made some researched and did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my case. I simply converted my specified date to DateTime, then I could compare it properly, as seen below. I hope it helps some people who has the same issue.

```
   foreach (Appointment a in appointments)
        {               
            if (a.LastModifiedTime >= Convert.ToDateTime(date))
            {
                i++;
                TAppointments app = new TAppointments(a.ICalUid.ToString(), a.Subject.ToString(), a.Start.ToString(), a.End.ToString(), a.LastModifiedTime.ToString());
                currentApp = app;
                tempList.Add(app);
                found = true;
            }

        }
```